# Facebook Android login get users email address

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using the Facebook registerCallBack method to get the current users information. The problem i am having is while trying to retrieve the email address.

```
// Callback registration
    FBLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            final Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if (profile != null) {

            }
            //Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this,"Wait...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                String email_id = object.getString("email");
                                String gender = object.getString("gender");
                                String facebook_id=profile.getId();
                                String f_name=profile.getFirstName();
                                String m_name=profile.getMiddleName();
                                String l_name=profile.getLastName();
                                String full_name=profile.getName();
                                String profile_image=profile.getProfilePictureUri(400, 400).toString();

                                Log.i("facebook_id",facebook_id);
                                Log.i("f_name",f_name);
                                Log.i("m_name",m_name);
                                Log.i("l_name",l_name);
                                Log.i("full_name",full_name);
                                Log.i("profile_image",profile_image);
                                Log.i("gender",gender);
                                Log.i("email_id",email_id+"");

                                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday, friends,albums"); 
            request.setParameters(parameters); 
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
```

Using this code i get the following log:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for email
```

I have made sure that the email is publicly available in case that was an issue as i had a similar problem with the Google Plus login script.

Comment: You need to ask for the email field

Comment: @wizkid I do, in the parameters email is specified

Comment: Oh, have you ask the user for email permission?

Comment: As @WizKid said, maybe this is a permissions issue when you set it: **"email" isn't holding by "user_profile"** permission. I get it with `LoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "..."))`.

Comment: @Fllo Where would I put that code? I'm not sure myself

Comment: When the user clicks on LoginButton, you initiate the LoginManager, and on this, you set permissions. You can find [an example in the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) (see Add LoginButton section). Just right after retrieving the button by its id, you have to set ReadPermissions(). You should pass an array, as my code above, with all permission you need (including email as well).

Comment: @Fllo Perfect, thank you. If you write an answer I can mark it as correct :)

Comment: Glad to help you with this - I added my answer below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment above, when you get the differents fields:

```
parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email, gender, birthday, friends, albums");
```

you certainly forgot the right permissions. Indeed, you probably set `"user_profile"` as follows:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_profile");
```

However, when you look at [the reference documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5), you can see that [`"email"`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-email) is a permission on its own, it's not included in [`"user_profile"`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-public_profile).

Therefore you have to set different permissions, included `"email"` as well, when you initiate the `LoginManager` (see [Add LoginButton section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)). Instead of getting only one permissions, you can set an array as:

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_profile", "email", "...", "..."));
```

Thanks to this, you will be able to retrieve the email address.